# Slideshow (FlexSlider) Issue on Shopify Site

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, flexslider

First time here on Stackoverflow and hoping to get an answer to what's going on with a FlexSlider issue on a clients Shopify site. Here's the reference link: http://fourflours.com.

Notice all looks good upon the first cycle through the slideshow....But let it play through a 2nd time and you'll notice the slideshow cycles past the 1st slide and immediately shows the 2nd slide. Below is the jQuery file that i'm pulling from:

http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0315/9969/t/5/assets/jquery.flexslider.js?6056

Please feel free to view the source code for full reference on what code i'm dealing with, I've commented around everything that has to do with the FlexSlider slideshow.

And to clarify what we're trying to do - We're just needing to get the slideshow to cycle through properly (like it does the first time) and not skip any slides on it's repeat back through.

Thanks in advance for anyone who can lend a 2nd set of eyes on this!
- Anthony

*** EDIT**
Below is a bit of the code that is relevant to this particular issue –

The javascript/css files that are linked within the < head > portion of the site (starting at line 43 in the source code):

• Javascript File: `//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0315/9969/t/5/assets/jquery.flexslider.js?6127`

```
$(function(){
    SyntaxHighlighter.all();
 });
 $(window).load(function(){
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        start: function(slider){
           $('body').removeClass('loading');
        }
     });
 });
```

Starting at line 336 in the source code is where the actual HTML portion of the slider starts and here's the code for it:

```
    <div class="flexslider"><ul class="slides">
      <!-- edit slides below / don't edit above here -->
    <li><a href="/pages/our-products"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0315/9969/t/5/assets/slideshow-1.jpg?6127"></a></li>
    <li><a href="/pages/our-products"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0315/9969/t/5/assets/slideshow-2.jpg?6127"></a></li>
    <li><a href="/collections/gifts"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0315/9969/t/5/assets/slideshow-3.jpg?6127"></a></li>
    <li><a href="/collections/platters"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0315/9969/t/5/assets/slideshow-4.jpg?6127"></a></li>
      <!-- end edit slides / don't edit below here -->
    </ul>
    </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0315/9969/t/5/assets/shCore.js?6127"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0315/9969/t/5/assets/shBrushXml.js?6127"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0315/9969/t/5/assets/shBrushJScript.js?6127"></script>

  <script src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0315/9969/t/5/assets/jquery.easing.js?6127"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0315/9969/t/5/assets/jquery.mousewheel.js?6127"></script>
  <script defer src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0315/9969/t/5/assets/demo.js?6127"></script>
```

Please let me know if I can better describe this. Again i'm still new to S.O. and i'm not 100% clear on the etiquette for posting these type of things just yet.

Comment: Hi @Joe - I'll edit the original post with the source code that is relevant to this problem.